# Count distinct values with conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, count, distinct

I have a dataframe as below :

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| id_doctor | id_patient | consumption | type_drug |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| d1        | p1         |        12.0 | bhd       |
| d1        | p2         |        10.0 | lsd       |
| d1        | p1         |         6.0 | bhd       |
| d1        | p1         |        14.0 | carboxyl  |
| d2        | p1         |        12.0 | bhd       |
| d2        | p1         |        13.0 | bhd       |
| d2        | p2         |        12.0 | lsd       |
| d2        | p1         |         6.0 | bhd       |
| d2        | p2         |        12.0 | bhd       |
+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to count distinct patients that take bhd with a consumption < 16.0 for each doctor.

I tried the following query2, but it doesn't work:

```py
dataframe.groupBy(col("id_doctor")).agg(
    countDistinct(col("id_patient")).where(
        col("type_drug") == "bhd" & col("consumption") < 16.0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `where` on your dataframe - this version delete the id_doctor where the count is 0 :

```
dataframe.where(
    col("type_drug") == "bhd" & col("consumption") < 16.0
).groupBy(
    col("id_doctor")
).agg(
    countDistinct(col("id_patient"))
)
```

Using this syntax, you can keep all the "doctors" :

```
dataframe.withColumn(
    "fg",
    F.when(
        (col("type_drug") == "bhd") 
        & (col("consumption") < 16.0),
        col("id_patient")
    )
).groupBy(
    col("id_doctor")
).agg(
    countDistinct(col("fg"))
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you want multiple aggregations in the same groupBy that don't share the same filters - in that case @mish1818's answer would be the best option.

Comment: @Brendan Their solution is exactly the same as the second I already posted but they just don't create the column first ....

Answer (score 10):

Another solution in PySpark without adding another column:

```py
dataframe.groupBy("id_doctor").agg(
    F.countDistinct(
        F.when(
            col("type_drug") == "bhd" & col("consumption") < 16.0, col("id_patient")
        ).otherwise(None)
    )
)
```

Comment: `otherwise(None)` is not needed: it will automatically return None for everything that does not match the `when` condition.

Answer (score 2):

And solution without adding additional column (Scala)

```
dataframe
    .groupBy("id_doctor")
    .agg(
        countDistinct(when(col("type_drug")==="bhd" && col("consumption") < 16.0))
    )
```