# Pyspark multiple simple aggregations best practice - countif/sumif format

Tags: pyspark

I'm relatively new to Pyspark and I'm looking for advice on the best way to make multiple simple aggregations on a long dataframe.

I have a dataframe of transactions where customers have multiple transactions a day, and I'd like to groupby customer and keep some variables like total sum, and some variables like countdistinct of the dates where a condition holds.

So I'd like to know for each customer:

- On how many days did they purchase from category A
- On how many weekend days did they make a purchase
- The total spend across all transactions
- Plus ideally also a few other things like transactions last month, maximum spend, maximum spend on the weekend etc.

So essentially quite a lot of "countifs" or "sumifs" in excel terminology.

I feel like it's not the best thing to calculate all of these separately like below and then join them together (as per the answer to [pyspark sql query : count distinct values with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004970/pyspark-sql-query-count-distinct-values-with-conditions)
), because I have quite a lot of customers so that join would be expensive, and since some customers don't make a transaction on any weekends, I think this would need to be a join not just a concatention:

```
total_variables = transactions.groupby('cust_id').agg(sum("spend").alias("total_spend")) 
weekend_variables = transactions.where(transactions.weekend_flag == "Y").groupby('cust_id').agg(countDistinct("date").alias("days_txn_on_weekend"))  
catA_variables = transactions.where(transactions.category == "CatA").groupby('cust_id').agg(countDistinct("date").alias("days_txn_cat_a")) 
final_df = total_variables.join(weekend_variables, col('total_variables.id') == col('weekend_variables.id'), 'left') \
                          .join(catA_variables, col('df1.id') == col('catA_variables.id'), 'left')
```

One approach is to make partially empty columns & then call count distint or sum on them, like this:

```
transactions_additional = transactions.withColumn('date_if_weekend',
                                                psf.when(psf.col("weekend_flag") == "Y",
                                                psf.col('date')).otherwise(psf.lit(None)))
                                      .withColumn('date_if_CatA',
                                                psf.when(psf.col("category") == "CatA",
                                                psf.col('date')).otherwise(psf.lit(None)))
final_df = total_variables .groupby('cust_id').agg(psf.countDistinct("date_if_weekend").alias("days_txn_on_weekend"),
                                                   psf.countDistinct("date_if_CatA").alias("days_txn_cat_a"),
                                                   psf.sum("spend").alias("total_spend"))
```

But this seems wasteful in terms of generating columns and might get out of hand with what I eventually want to calculate.

I think I could do it in pyspark-sql with countdistinct and case, but I hope there is a better way using the pyspark syntax - maybe using custom aggregation UDFs in the format:

```
aggregated_df = transactions.groupby('cust_id').agg(<something that returns total spend>,
                                                    <something that returns days purchased cat A>,
                                                    <something that returns days purchased on the weekend>,)
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

spark `pandas_udf` functions are quite usefull and readable for aggregated results.
Here is sample code, for your desired output, you can extend to add any other aggregated results.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,IntegerType,LongType,StructType,StructField,StringType
import pandas as pd

#you can add last month maximum spend, maximum spend on the weekend etc and 
#update agg_data function
agg_schema = StructType(
    [StructField("cust_id", StringType(), True),
     StructField("days_txn_on_weekend", IntegerType(), True),
     StructField("days_txn_cat_a", IntegerType(), True),
     StructField("total_spend", IntegerType(), True)
     ]
)

@F.pandas_udf(agg_schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def agg_data(pdf):
    days_txn_on_weekend =  pdf.query("weekend_flag == 'Y'")['date'].nunique()
    days_txn_cat_a = pdf.query("category == 'CatA'")['date'].nunique()
    total_spend = pdf['spend'].sum()
    return pd.DataFrame([(pdf.cust_id[0],days_txn_on_weekend,days_txn_cat_a,total_spend)])

transactions = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190101, 'N', 10),
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190101, 'N', 20),
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190105, 'Y',40),
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190105, 'Y',10),
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190112, 'Y', 20),
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190113, 'Y', 10),
    ('cust_1', 'CatA', 20190101, 'N',20),
    ('cust_1', 'CatB', 20190105, 'Y', 50),
    ('cust_1', 'CatB', 20190105, 'Y', 50),
    ('cust_2', 'CatA', 20190115, 'N', 10),
    ('cust_2', 'CatA', 20190116, 'N', 20),
    ('cust_2', 'CatA', 20190117, 'N', 40),
    ('cust_2', 'CatA', 20190119, 'Y', 10),
    ('cust_2', 'CatA', 20190119, 'Y', 20),
    ('cust_2', 'CatA', 20190120, 'Y', 10),
    ('cust_3', 'CatB', 20190108, 'N', 10),
    ],
    ['cust_id','category','date','weekend_flag','spend']
)
transactions.groupBy('cust_id').apply(agg_data).show()
```

which results

```
+-------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
|cust_id|days_txn_on_weekend|days_txn_cat_a|total_spend|
+-------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
| cust_2|                  2|             5|        110|
| cust_3|                  0|             0|         10|
| cust_1|                  3|             4|        230|
+-------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for.
I wonder whether there is a way to improve performance of these by defining those functions in Scala?